# PHP str_replace not replacing "AND AND"

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm running into a strange problem with str_replace,

I would like to replace an instance of "AND AND" in a string. Like so:

```
$filters->sql = str_replace("AND AND","test",$filters->sql);
```

However, it seems that str_replace can't find this "AND AND", while

```
$filters->sql = str_replace("AND ","test",$filters->sql);
```

works, and also

```
$filters->sql = str_replace("AND","test",$filters->sql);
```

works.

I've echoed out the string multiple times and copy-pasted to see that I have the right string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible there is more than one white space character between the AND AND.

Please try this:

```
$filters->sql = preg_replace('/AND\s+AND/', 'test', $filters->sql);
```